# Worthy iStat equivalent

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring

I'm looking for an [iStat](http://islayer.com/apps/istatpro/) equivalent for Ubuntu that can do the following:

- show my current CPU usage in the top bar (preferably only 1 for my both cores combined)
- show my current up- and download speed in the top bar
- show my current RAM usage in the top bar
- give more detailed information when one of the indicators is clicked
- more important: show CPU and battery temperatures

I'm running the latest Ubuntu version and will always be.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks on my Mac:
[image: iStat on my Mac]

Comment: Please state what ubuntu version you are running.  You should have a look at this question about what application indicators are available for Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available

Comment: @StephenMyall I edited my question. I run 12.04 now and will update as soon as new versions are available.

Answer (score 1):

[**System Load Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) seems to be what I was looking for.

It can be found in the Software Center as well.

I can show CPU usage, RAM usage and network speeds in the top bar. Only temperatures it cannot, but it already does a really good job doing these 3 things!